# Using an onedit script to toggle the format of a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to google app's script. This is my [sample spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OxoC7FFFH1AdVLiCklGWRL4R_Zv6Xm5tjc7s_URaAsY/edit?usp=sharing) I'm trying to write a script where a checkbox toggles the format of a column (metric/imperial units). It works only for the first case, not the second. I'm not sure why the (e.value == true/false) doesn't seem to be working.

```
function onEdit (e) {
  var Name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
  Logger.log(Name)
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C19' && e.value == 'TRUE') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("K2:K89").setNumberFormat("0.00oz")
  }
    else if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C19' && e.value == 'FALSE'){
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("K2:K89").setNumberFormat("0.00g")
    }}
```

Comment: The first case is (e.value == true), it successfully changes the format to "0.00oz" but it does not work in the case of (e.value == false).

Comment: Your use of `getRange` from a `Spreadsheet` with a string that does not include a sheet specification means this will only format the first sheet, even if you edited a different sheet. You can get the edited sheet from the edit trigger's event object, or from `getActiveSheet`

Comment: When I'm testing it, `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()` successfully returns me the correct name of the spreadsheet I'm currently editing. So I would expect that `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange` would work. I have also tried appending the name of the spreadsheet to the range: `"& Name &"!K2:K89"` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code fragment that will work to change the format of columns based on checkbox input:

```
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'C19')
  { 
      if (e.value == 'TRUE') { 
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("K2:K59").setNumberFormat("000.00lb");
      }
      else
     {
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("K2:K59").setNumberFormat("000.00oz");
     }
  }

  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'C18'){

    if (e.value == 'TRUE') {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("L2:L59").setNumberFormat("##0.00gr");
    }
    else
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("L2:L59").setNumberFormat('##0.00"%"');
    }
  }
```

This allows the format of cols `K` and `L` to be changed. This is just for illustrative purposes and you need also to recalculate metric/imperial weights etc.

The main problem you had I would guess is `(e.value == true)` should be `(e.value == 'TRUE')`.

Also you may need to use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` instead of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet()`.

**NOTE:** By experimentation I discovered that the value returned by a check box seems to be the strings `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` and not a boolean value. So `if(e.value)` does not work to test for boolean `true` etc as you would expect. I am open to correction by higher authorities on this, but the `(e.value == 'TRUE')` form was the only one that I could make work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! It works now. You're right - the value of the checkbox did not return a boolean value. I tried (e.value == true) and (e.value == "true") but it only worked with (e.value = 'true'). Thank you so much!

Comment: One last thing, my script only seems to work for one spreadsheet only and I'm not sure why. If I use `Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName())` it fetches the correct active sheet, but it does not format the column.

Comment: Ok great. It would be good for everyone if you accept the reply so that the question can be closed. Click the tick under the vote up/down arrows at top left of reply. You can also vote up if you like. Neither of these are compulsory I should add!

Comment: Regarding only working on one sheet, I don't know exactly, but you should get used to using the `View -> Log` and `View -> Execution Script` to check your code for errors. Generally, Google Sheet can be temperamental and sometimes slow to execute. If the problem persists I suggest a new question, and I will take a look tomorrow (Australian Time) if no one has replied.